# Google Lighthouse and Google PageSpeed Insights report Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, pagespeed, googlebot, lighthouse

When I get the website report, I see an issue with Google Analytics under the Performance section.
[image: Screenshot from Lighthouse]
Is there a way to fix it? For now all I've done is just turn off GA loading if the user-agent contains Google bots.

```
if (/googlebot|lighthouse/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.ga=function(){};
} else {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
}
```

Comment: This won't help, because the Core Web Vitals is measured by Google based on real visits to your site from real users.